# Objective C - UIImage resizing not working

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, image-resizing

I have a program that fetches an image from the library, but I'm using code I found online to resize that image so that it can fit on the screen (basically making it 640x960), but then it would still be too big to display, so in another UIImage I'm copying the first resized image and re-resizing this one to make it about 1/4 of the screen (or 160x240). The code is this:

for ViewController.h:

```
UIImage *img;
UIImage *thumb;

-(UIImage*) scaleImage: (UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize;
```

(this of course, is only the code related to my problem)

for ViewController.m

```
-(UIImage*) scaleImage: (UIImage*)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

and in the same m file on another function, the scaleImage function is called when pressing a button with these lines:

```
[self scaleImage:img toSize:CGSizeMake(640, 960)];
thumb = img;
[self scaleImage:thumb toSize:CGSizeMake(160, 240)];
```

In the project I've previously been able to successfully provide an image for `img` using `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];` which would be the image chosen from the library. I've already "file owned" everything so that this function takes place (and it does because I create an UIAlert within it and it shows, and a NSLog to print out when scaleImage starts and it does, twice), but the image is never re-sized!! Does anyone know why?? Please let me know, thank you for anyone who comments with help or suggestions!!

Comment: When I tried to resize the image to a smaller scale, the image was actually larger.  I found your scaleImage code in your question above and that worked.  Thanks for asking the question and posting your code.  :-)

Comment: and thank you for posting this, makes me feel I'm contributing more than I actually do =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `scaleImage` method *returns* the scaled image, for example

```
thumb = [self scaleImage:img toSize:CGSizeMake(640, 960)];
```